# linux how to allow user to read/write/delete files created from root in a specific folder

Tags: linux, permissions, directory, chmod, rights

I use `automysqlbackup` to backup my mysql database.

The problem is I can only run this program using `sudo automysqlbackup`. This program dumps the backup into my folder `/home/user/backup` but theses files are owned by root and when I connect via ftp to this folder I cannot delete or read them.

Is it possible that any files created by root in the folder `/home/user/backup` can be read/write/deleted by user "user" ?

Or is there a way I can run the `automysqlbackup` with user "user" ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Couldn't write a bash script, which calls the backup and then changes the permissions with chmod ?

Comment: i could but i'm relative new to linux .. Isnt there an easier way ?

Comment: Finnaly, I used a bash script as you noticed

Answer (score 0):

For the first question : you can use SUID, for example :

```
chmod 4750 file1.txt
```

Here in **4750**, *4* indicates SUID bit set, *7* for full permissions for owner, *5* for read and execute permissions for group, and no permissions for others.

For example, you can chmod your command, and your user may execute your backup command

For the second question, you can upgrade the user rights with the file /etc/sudoers.

If you need more help, say me.

Comment: In case the link goes down (which _does_ happen occasionally), could you please edit your answer to include a summary of how to use the SUID from the link?

Comment: could you provide me an example for my case with SUID ?

Comment: I Updated my first post